# How to compare open connection string with connection string from config file

Tags: c#, connection-string

Hi all I want to check if my opened connection is same as the connection string from config file.

I was trying something like this:

```
if(con.ConnectionString == ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con1"].ConnectionString);
```

The first part is giving me right value and second part should give me the same string.

EDIT:
This is my entire connection string as I didn't want to bother you with the details:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastDBcheck).TotalSeconds > 10 && con.ConnectionString==ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con1"].ConnectionString)
```

Comment: I can't compare those two strings. I am not passing the if statement. and yes they are the same

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not passing the if statement"? Do you get an exception (e.g. NullReferenceException)? Does the code just block indefinitely? If you *don't* pass the if statement, what *does* happens?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and start debugging. When you reach it, use the `Locals`, `Watch` or `Immediate Window` to examine these three variables: `lastDBcheck`, `con` and `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con1"]`. There are four possible outcomes: 1) current time is <10s after `lastDBcheck`, 2) `con` is `null` and an exception is thrown, 3) there is no connection string named `Con1` so the indexer also returns `null` and again, an exception is thrown, or 4) strings are, well, different. Your code is correct, but you might need to check for nulls, depending on the source of `con`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `==` to compare the values of strings is correct in C#.

If your code isn't working it's most likely due to either:

- The values aren't actually the same (maybe one has extra whitespace or a small change).
- You are getting an exception.

To avoid the latter case I suggest that you check that your objects are not null before dereferencing them.

```
var con1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con1"];

if (con != null && con1 != null && con.ConnectionString == con1.ConnectionString) {
    // Connection strings are the same.
}
```

Comment: I dont have semi colon. I must put it while writing question

Comment: @denonth: "I must put it while writing question" Err... why? Have you made any other modifications to your code before you posted it?

Comment: If no semi colon is in your code, then I fail to see what the issue is. Are you getting an error? are the not evaluating as being the same. How about some information, please?

Comment: connection string from config file has a password value and in con.connectionstring there is not the pass. what do you suggest

Answer (score 2):

I think this will explain your problem:

```
The .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server does not persist or return 
the password in a connection string unless you set Persist Security Info to true.
```

False is the default.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score -1):

When comparing strings, it's better to use String1.Equals(String2).  This will compare the values of the strings.

Comment: Comparing with `==` also compares the values of the strings. And strings are [interned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned.aspx), so if two strings have the same value, they will also have the same reference.

Comment: Interesting.  This is a difference between C# and Java I did not know.

Comment: Java and C# appear very similar, until you realize they are not :)